Let the number be $\sqrt{111...1}$ where we have 2024 digits of 1. Find its first 1013 digits.
The problem
Let the number be $\sqrt{111...1}$ where we have 2024 digits of 1. Find its first 1013 digits.
my idea
To be honest I don't know how to start this problem. I tried finding a rule for all the numbers of this type and saw that $\sqrt{11..11}$ with an even number $n$ of 1 has the form $33...3$ with $n/2$ digits of 3, but I don't know if this helps or how to demonstrate this fact. I also thought of the fact we have to find the first 1013 digits which is $= 2024/2+1$
I don't want to just calculate them by hand or something, I want a rational demonstration.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

My first try, which might not succeed, would be to note that $~111...111~$ : with 2024 digits equals $~\dfrac{10^{2024} - 1}{9}.$

@user2661923 i think you meant $10^{2024}$, didnt you?

Yes, comment edited.

@user2661923 actually i think its 2025...

No.  Consider that $~11 = \dfrac{10^2 - 1}{9}.$

Hey silly question but what do first digits mean? the ones at the front or back (one's place)?

@uggupuggu Of course, the one s at the front

Consider the number a=333....333.3 with 1013 digits ( 1012 before the decimal point, 1 after). Try to evaluate $a^2$ ; if you can proove that this number is lower than our $x=\sqrt{1111...}$, you are in.  And to evaluate $a^2$, you can probably consider $b=\frac{10^{13}}{3}$, and calculate $b^2-a^2$.

@Lourrran To be honest, i dont understand your idea. I would really be grateful if you would be more explicit or post an answer

@PamMunozRyan I believe Lourrran is trying to say that you should show that a < x < b
Where a = 3333...3.3 (1013 3's) and b = 333...3.333... = 10^1012/3
Proving x < b is easy, but in order to prove a < x, you should square both sides and compare
When you prove a < x < b, you will show that the first 1013 digits must be _____

Show that $$ 10^{1012} - \frac{1}{2\times 10^{1012}} > \sqrt{ 10^{2024 } -1} >  10^{1012} - \frac{1}{2 \times 10^{1012}} - \frac{1}{  10 ^{3036+1}}.$$
Conclude that the first 2024 digits are 3, followed by a 1.
Further followed by 2024 6's.
You can continue by further bounding $ \sqrt{x^2 -1 }$ with the Maclaurin series. With a bit more work, show that it is further followed by 24999..., with 4046 9's.  What's the next chunk?

Good addition Mr. Lin

Let $a = 3333....3.3 (1013 \space 3's) = \frac{10^{1013}-1}{30} $
$x = \sqrt{111...} = \frac{\sqrt{10^{2024}-1}}{3}$
$b = \frac{\sqrt{10^{2024}}}{3} = \frac{10^{1012}}{3} = 333..33.\bar{3}$
Clearly $x<b$
Consider $a^2$ and $x^2$
$a^2 =({\frac{10^{1012}-0.1}{3})}^2 = \frac{10^{2024}-2\cdotp10^{1011}+0.01}{9}$
$x^2=\frac{10^{2024}-1}{9}$
Thus $x^2>a^2 \implies x > a$
$$a<x<b$$
$$3333....3.3<x<3333....3.\bar{3}$$
Thus the first 1013 digits are 3

No, $\frac{10^{1012}}{3}$ has 1012 3's in front of the decimal point

As @user2661923 has stated, we can rewrite $111...1$ ($2024$ ones) as
$$\frac{10^{2024} -1 } {9}$$
We can rewrite as
$$\frac{1} {3} \sqrt {10^{2024}-1}$$
$1$ is negligible compared to $10^{2024}$, so we can use binomial approximation for large numbers which is $$\sqrt {a^2 - b} \approx a - \frac {b} {2a}$$
Let $a=10^{1012}$ and $b=1$,
$$\sqrt {10^{2024} - 1} \approx 10^{2024} - \frac {1} {2}×10^{-1012}$$
Hence,
$$\sqrt {111...1} \approx \frac {1}{3} (10^{2024} - \frac {1} {2}×10^{-1012})$$
$$= \frac{10^{1012}}{3} - \frac{1}{6} × 10^{-1012}$$
$$\frac{10^{1012}}{3}=333\dots333.3333\dots$$
Now we subtract $\frac{1}{6} ×10^{-1012}$ from this
$$333...333.3333 - 0.00\dots01666\dots$$
Keep in mind that for the zeroes of $\frac{1}{6} ×10^{-1012}$, there are $1011$ of them. Moreover, note the integer part of $\frac{10^{1012}} {3}$ has $1012$ digits.
This means that when you subtract the terms, the first $1013$ terms are all $3$.
